# passing multiple objects as parameters to mvc 6 action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have an MVC 5 project that is working fine, and I need to migrate that project to MVC 6 with.net core. After managing to tweak everything to work I got stuck with a problem: Many of my actions accept more than 1 object as a parameter. The model binder MVC 5 is using has no problem with that, but MVC 6 seems to place null in all the parameters of such actions, I guess it's part of the unification of MVC and WebAPI. My question is if there is anyway around it **without adding another model library of request wrapper objects.** 
for example:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetVersionData(OvlEnvironment environment, Pipeline pipeline)
    {
        BL.SetEnviromentVersion(pipeline, environment);
        return PartialView("_Version", environment);
    }
```

On the mvc 5 project ajax requests containing json data in the form

```
{ "environment" : {*Data...*},
  "pipeline" : {*Data...*}
}
```

were accepted. In mvc 6 both objects in response to the same request appear to be null.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a concrete example

Comment: ok, added an example

Comment: Try to add [FromBody] e.g. GetVersionData([FromBody] OvlEnvironment environment, [FromBody] Pipeline pipeline)

Comment: tried, didnt work

Comment: Yeah, you can't add `[FromBody]` twice..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to give the ASP.NET Core MVC Framework the hint, that data to bind to the model is to be found in the body of the post request. This is done via the [[FromBody] attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding).

> [FromBody]: Use the configured formatters to bind data from the
>   request body. The formatter is selected based on content type of the
>   request.

By design it is not possible to bind multiple parameters to one JSON source as it is described [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2981). In order to avoid additional model classes you can use a generic JObject like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetVersionData([FromBody] JObject data)
{
    var environment = data["environment"].ToObject<OvlEnvironment>();
    var pipline = data["pipeline"].ToObject<Pipeline>();

    BL.SetEnviromentVersion(pipeline, environment);
    return PartialView("_Version", environment);
}
```

Comment: "My question is if there is anyway around it without adding another model library of request wrapper objects.". Since i'm sure i'm not the first to run into this, I thought someone might have a solution

Comment: If have added the link to a GitHub issue, where it is stated, that it is not possible to bind the body JSON input to multiple parameter objects. Therefore some kind of other solution has to be sought. By using JObject (JSON.net is used internally by ASP.NET Core MVC, so no other model library is added) you can avoid defining classes for data transport. The other solution is to combine multiple parameters to one object.

Comment: I would think of a custom model binder\formatter to deal with the issue, sadly I dont have the time nor feel like writing one, moreover its pity to do so since microsoft already did it with earlier versions of MVC. My goal is not to change a lot of code during the migration. I think that creating strongly typed wrapper object is actually a better solution than just accepting JObject with all my actions as if I was working with a loosely typed language. in both solution I'm changing a lot of code. I'm looking for a way that would let me keep my controller as is. If there isn't one, life sucks

Comment: Can you have model validation and xml formater with JObject?

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but I also ran into this problem.

I think the accepted answer is right, in ASP.NET MVC5 it was possible to seek the HttpRequest.InputStream, but this is not allowed anymore in ASP.NET Core 2. So the work-around could be to read the stream once and store the parsed JObject in the ModelState (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelstatedictionary?view=aspnetcore-2.1). Simple tests show that this approach could work.

This is an example of such an approach:

```
public class JsonMultiParameterModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private static IModelBinder DefaultModelBinder;
    private const string JSONKEY = "json_body";

    public JsonMultiParameterModelBinder(IModelBinder defaultModelBinder)
    {
        DefaultModelBinder = defaultModelBinder;
    }

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var httpContext = bindingContext.HttpContext;
        var stream = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body;
        if (httpContext.Request.ContentType.Contains("application/json"))
        {
            JObject jobject = null;
            ModelStateEntry entry = null;
            bindingContext.ModelState.TryGetValue(JSONKEY, out entry);
            if (entry == null)
            {

                using (var readStream = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
                using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(readStream))
                {
                    jobject = JObject.Load(jsonReader);
                }

                bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(JSONKEY, jobject, null);
            }
            else
            {
                jobject = entry.RawValue as JObject;
            }
            var jobj = jobject[bindingContext.FieldName];

            if (jobj == null)
            {
                httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500; // error has occured
                throw new JsonReaderException(string.Format("The rootnode '{0}' is not found in the Json message.", bindingContext.ModelName));
            }

            object obj = null;

            var JSONSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

            try
            {
                obj = jobj.ToObject(bindingContext.ModelType, JSONSerializer);
                bindingContext.Model = obj;
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(obj);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500; // error has occured
                throw ex;
            }

        }
        return DefaultModelBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
    }
}
```

And the provider for this binder :

```
public class JsonMultiParameterModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (context.Metadata.IsComplexType)
        {
            ComplexTypeModelBinderProvider p = new ComplexTypeModelBinderProvider();

            return new JsonMultiParameterModelBinder(p.GetBinder(context));
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Register in Startup.cs:

```
        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new JsonMultiParameterModelBinderProvider());
        }
```